# Azure Logic App fails to send message to slack

Tags: azure, slack-api, azure-logic-apps

We have some Logic Apps setup that monitor our various sites and a Slack connection set up. If a non-200 status code is returned, it sends a message to our alerts channel in Slack. We have about 10 sites that are monitored.

The first was setup, tested the cloned for the other sites.

The issue we're having is that they all seem to work bar one.

The site in question was offline this morning (after host updated the server at 3am this morning) and I can in the Azure log the trigger was fired - but no message in Slack.

I changed the Condition to "status equals 200" (to ensure it always fires), ran it manually and still see no message.

As mentioned this logic app was cloned from one that did work so the only thing that changes from app to app is the site URL and the contents of the slack message.

Being relatively new to various Azure features this was a bit of "R&D" for Logic Apps so I'm not really sure what to check.
Any obvious gotchas we should be aware of? Any pointers you can give to help resolve this would be great.

NB: I added Slack API as a tag to this but as this part is handled by Azure and it's working for other Logic Apps feel free to remove.

Comment: This is not an answer to your problem, but why don't you just use an existing monitoring service, like https://uptimerobot.com/ that does all that reliably? Including the connection to Slack.

Comment: We already use Site247 for key sites but as I mentioned this is just an experiment playing around with Logic Apps and increasing our understanding of what they can do and how we manage them.

Comment: If the trigger fired (by default it fires if response to polling request has status code 200), then you should see a corresponding run started (you should see a list of runs on the logic app blade in azure portal). If you click on any of the runs, it will open a monitoring blade where you can inspect inputs, outputs and status of all the operations (trigger and actions). This should help investigate what exactly happened.